# Debug option invalid in sql developer tool

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I having a procedure, which output doesn't show in output variable tab in sql developer.
Actually i have to validate the data in the table used inside the procedure. So i used inbulit debugging option in sql developer tool. But i shows below error message

```
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '192.168.7.129', '56229' )
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
This session requires DEBUG CONNECT SESSION and DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE user privileges.
Process exited.
```

I know we can debug using

```
dbms_output.put_line();
Dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
```

But above two takes a lot time and irritation while debug.

If anyone know an effevtive way of debugging using sql developer, Please let me know.

Comment: The error message tells you that you need additional privileges for the user you are connected as. That isn't a SQL Developer problem. You need to ask your DBA to grant you those privileges.

Comment: Read this article: https://blog.yannickjaquier.com/oracle/minimum-privileges-plsql-debugging.html

Comment: @AlexPoole Ok... can you share the effective method of debugging if you know?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; this is an effective method, you just need your account to be set up properly to use is.

Comment: @AlexPoole I don't have a debugging privilage in my environment. So i need alternate method.

Answer (score 1):

[I have tried to cover everything you need to know here.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/06/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-the-plsql-debugger/)

[image]

- Privs Required
- ACL for JDWP
- DBMS_DEBUG Alternative
- How to start the debugger
- Watches, Breakpoints, Stepping Into other units

I even have [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/hillbillyToad/debugging-plsql-with-oracle-sql-developer?ref=https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/06/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-the-plsql-debugger/) and a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBA8gL8NyXE).

This is of course in ADDITION to our docs on the debugger feature in SQL Developer.